# How to implement shared library in jenkins, without configuring "Global Pipeline Libraries" in "Manage Jenkins"?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, shared-libraries, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-shared-libraries

Since I don't have access to "Manage Jenkins" menu in my organization, I'm unable to configure my shared library in "Global Pipeline Libraries" in "Manage Jenkins".

Is there any other way to implement this, without configuring in Manage Jenkins?

(or)

Is it possible to configure "Global Pipeline Libraries" part through pipeline script, irrespective of access privileges?

If possible, requesting you to share some code snippets in the answer.

Comment: See https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#dynamic-retrieval. This has limitation though.

Comment: Thanks @DibakarAditya , found the way to do it. you can see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without configuring in "Manage Jenkins". We can use "LibraryIdentifier" in Pipeline script to load the libraries in the jenkins build.

Comment: What do you mean?  Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

***Load the library***

you can load the library from source control (like git) like this:

```
def myLib= library(
    identifier: 'myLib@master', retriever: modernSCM
    (
        [
            $class: 'GitSCMSource',
            remote: 'https://bitbucket.org/shaybc/commonlib.git',
            credentialsId: 'bitbucketCreds'
        ]
    )
)
```

***Groovy class from the library***

assuming this is the groovy class:

```
package my.domain

class Tester
{
    public static String staticTest()
    {
        return "this is from a static method";
    }

    public String test()
    {
        return "this is from an instance method";
    }
}
```

***Call the methods from scripted pipeline***

then you call a static method like this:

```
myLib.my.domain.Tester.staticTest();
```

and an instance method like this:

```
// call the constructor (you can also call a constructor with parameters)
def tester = myLib.my.domain.Tester.new();

// call your instance method
tester.test();
```

***read more:***

1. [loading libraries dynamically](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#loading-libraries-dynamically)
2. [the difference between @Library annotation and library step](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/360018431532-Difference-between-the-library-step-and-the-Library-annotation)
3. [private shared library by example](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2019/05/private-jenkins-shared-libraries.html)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in some of the answers above, you can load the library at runtime using library **identifier** or you can also configure the **library at folder level** of the Jenkins job that you're trying to run.
In most of the cases, the developers don't get admin access to Jenkins. However, they are allowed to access and update configurations at folder level. You can check if you have those privileges. It would be more convenient that loading libraries at runtime for all your pipeline scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm loading a shared library, actually just things from the `vars/` directory, using the same mechanism as the other answers, but we can make it a bit terser ([thanks to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49112612/1410035)):

```
library(identifier: "@some-branch", retriever: legacySCM(scm))
```

Normally you'd put some kind of identifier before the `@` but it serves no purpose here because all the things we import (groovy files from `vars/`) create their own global var named after the filename. So we can omit that identifier and just specify the branch (of the current repo).

As long as your pipeline file is loaded from SCM, you can make the `retriever` param pretty short too. I've seen `modernSCM()` used elsewhere but that didn't work for me, whereas `legacySCM()` does.

Note: we're using a function call `library()` and *not* the annotation `@Library()`. They seem to be different/not interchangeable.